# How is HTML DOM's getElementsByClassName() so efficient?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I had to make a recursive version of `getElementsByClassName` for a class I'm taking and after I finished I compared it to the native `HTMLElement.getElementsByClassName()`.

I found that on average my code is **30% ± 2%** less efficient, yet when accounting for *non-instant* runs I find that I am only **1.5%± 0.5%** less efficient. I can't find the native code online anywhere but I am curious, what does it implement to have so many instant results? Does it use closure scope to memorize past inputs or is it something more complicated? My only thought is that I might be losing efficiency from using JQuery but while writing this I realized I indeed didn't need to use JQuery and changed:

```
var myClassArray = $(me.classList);
var myChildren = $(me.childNodes);
```

to:

```
var myClassArray = me.classList;
var myChildren = me.childNodes;
```

With my new implementation I  that on average My code is **11% ± 1%** less efficient, yet when accounting for *non-instant* runs I find that I am only **1.01%± 0.005%** less efficient. I am now even more intrigued to know how it achieves so many instant results, as my version is virtually just as efficient when not counting instant runs.

```js
/**
 * Recursive version of .getElementsByClassName.
 *
 * Only elements with ALL of the classNames specified are selected.
 *
 * @param {String} className the target class name
 * @param {HTMLElement} lastMeChild the child of the last recursive element
 * @returns {Array} Return array of elements with the targeted className
 */
var getElementsByClassName = function(className, lastMeChild) {
  var me;
  if (lastMeChild) {
    me = lastMeChild;
  } else {
    me = document.body;
  }
  var myClassArray = me.classList;
  var myChildren = me.childNodes;
  var matchingElements = [];
  // Detect classes with multiple Strings as class name ex: class="red apple"
  var classNames = '';
  if (myClassArray !== undefined) {
    for (var myClassName = 0; myClassName < myClassArray.length; myClassName++) {
      classNames += ' ' + myClassArray[myClassName];
    }
  }
  classNames += ' ';
  // In order to support multiStr classNames add space at beginning
  // and end of className to filter strings conatining same chars
  // ex: 'targetClassN ameButNotQuite' or 'ButNotQuitetargetClassN ame'
  var uniqClassName = ' ' + className + ' ';
  if (classNames.includes(uniqClassName)) {
    // I have the target in my class
    matchingElements.push(me);
  }
  // Check if I have children
  if (myChildren !== undefined) {
    for (var child = 0; child < myChildren.length; child++) {
      matchingElements.push(getElementsByClassName(className, myChildren[child]));
    }
  }
  //Flatten the array so we hae a neat array of depth 1
  return matchingElements.flat(Infinity);
};

// Benchmarking:
var avg1 = [];
var avg2 = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 50000; x++) {
  var startTime1 = performance.now();
  var result = getElementsByClassName('targetC lassName');
  var endTime1 = performance.now();
  avg1.push(endTime1 - startTime1);

  var startTime2 = performance.now();
  var expectedNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('targetC lassName');
  var expectedArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(expectedNodeList);
  var endTime2 = performance.now();
  avg2.push(endTime2 - startTime2);
}
const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
var av1 = average(avg1);
var av2 = average(avg2);
console.log('Mine: ' + av1 + 'ms OG: ' + av2 + 'ms');
console.log((av1 < av2) ? ('Mine is ' + (Math.round(((av2 / av1) + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000) + '% more efficient') : ('OG is ' + (Math.round(((av1 / av2) + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000) + '% more efficient'));

var av1 = average(avg1.filter(val => val !== 0));
var av2 = average(avg2.filter(val => val !== 0));
console.log('\nNon-Instant: \n\nMine: ' + av1 + 'ms OG: ' + av2 + 'ms');
console.log((av1 < av2) ? ('Mine is ' + (Math.round(((av2 / av1) + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000) + '% more efficient') : ('OG is ' + (Math.round(((av1 / av2) + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000) + '% more efficient'));
```

```html
<div class="targetC lassName"></div>
<div class="otherClassName targetC lassName"></div>
<div>
  <div class="targetC lassName"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="targetC lassName">
    <div class="targetC lassName"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div class="targetC lassName"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="targetC lassName"></div>
  <div class="targetC lassName"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="someOtherDiv">
    <div class="targetC lassNameButNotQuite innerDiv">
      <span class="targetC lassName">Some text for this span.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="targetC lassName randomClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="paragraph text targetC lassName">
  <p class="intro targetC lassName">
    Text for the paragraph tag.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="someOtherDiv">
    <div class="ButNotQuitetargetC lassName innerDiv">
      <span class="targetC lassName">Some text for this span.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Native methods have different efficiencies, per browser implementation, and are **not** written in javascript, hence, faster than your javascript-written implementation.